# Call to a member function chunk() on array - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array in a variable which contains about 700 names. Iterating over the 700 names can be an issue since the array is large and could cause delay so i want to use chunk to see if it there will be no delay in my application.

In my code below, when i run the application, it throws the error

> > Call to a member function chunk() on array - Laravel

Is it possible i could chunk the data into pieces and iterate over the pieces so the application does not hang due to large data ?

PS: I am new to laravel PHP and sorry for my bad english.

**Controller.php**

```
 $myData =  $arrayList->chunk(ceil(($arrayList->count())/5));
       foreach($chunks as $chunk){
           Log::info('Chunking My Data');
           Log::info($chunk);
       }
```

Comment: Change array into a collection first, then call chunk. `collect($arrayList)->chunk(5)` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-chunk

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native array_chunk function, for example:

```
$myData = range(1, 10000);
foreach (array_chunk($myData, ceil(count($myData)/5)) as $chunk) {
    var_dump($chunk);
}
```